# PayPal guest checkout not available in certain countries

Tags: react-native, paypal

I'm integrating a react native app with PayPal's REST API and all has gone quite smoothly. However, when I click through, the buyer does not get the option to complete the purchase as a guest. I'm using a [v1/payments integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1); The transaction works if I login or create an account, but is it possible to let buyers pay without having to login?

I have researched and done most things people say you should do, like having a business account, enable guest payments, etc.

I tried using this github as an approach to using REST API, it works fine but if it helps: https://github.com/tonynguyenit18/paypal-RN-intergration

Comment: Is it possible those certain countries have regulations against guest purchases?

Comment: I found this https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional. It states that "*This feature is available to Premier and Business account holders only." Also, have you tried reaching out to PayPal dev community about this specific issue? You might have better luck that way.

Comment: That might be, unfortunately I have not find a list of countires in their documentation to show which countries allow guest payments and which don't.

Comment: Related (possibly) to my first post: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/bigcommerce/security/prohibited-countries

Comment: Seems like i get error "Can't find the page. The page does not exist for me.

Comment: I am not familiarized with PayPal API at all. I was just trying to help you by looking for info. Good luck to you. My advice is to contact the PayPal dev community for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a REST API issue. You are getting the expected behavior of the PayPal Checkout in general. Guest checkout is available on a case-by-case basis. Very many factors -- such as the country of the buyer, IP address, repeated payment attempts, and testing payments to one's own account in the live environment -- are used to determine guest eligibility.

When a checkout is not guest-eligible, the buyer can still enter their card details but will also need to choose a password to create an account in the process.

Again, this is just how the PayPal Checkout works in general.

By the way, the v1/payments API is deprecated. You should use 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

Comment: I don't know anything about PayPal API, but I also saw that v1 was deprecated. As a general rule, you should stay away from deprecated code; ESPECIALLY when you are just starting to create something new. I upvoted your answer based on this observation.

Comment: v1/payments *specifically* is deprecated, as there are newer replacements that are major revisions and hence use v2 in the URL scheme. Other APIs still use v1 URLs, for example subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I can see that and I will try to use v2 instead.